# How to connect to docker postgresql from host machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo

I am trying to connect my app (Odoo 14) on my host machine (MacOS) to PostgreSQL 15 docker container.

This is docker-compose used to create PostgreSQL container:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres_odoo_local
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - local-odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  local-odoo-db-data:
```

And this is Odoo configuration related to DB:

```
# Database parameters
db_password = odoo
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
dbfilter = .*
```

I even tried using `dh_host = 172.19.0.2` parameter, but that also didn't work. I got the IP from docker inspect. It was in networks section and IPAddress key. (This might not be correct value as I am very new to docker)

When running Odoo I get this error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I found out that Odoo expects socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" but PostgreSQL container is listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

I am very new to docker.
I am more than happy to provide additional information if needed.